# Does this piece of code represent a design pattern?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

In my base framework I like to have classes that I can reuse in several projects. Most often these are generic to allow for flexibility.

I have one tiny little header that I use to store data in and get the data easily.

```
#pragma once
#include <map>
#include <string>

namespace BaseFrameWork
{
template<class TValue, class TKey = std::string>
class Provider
{
public:
  static TValue& Get(TKey const& key);
private:
  static std::map<TKey, TValue> _dataMap;
};
}
```

Yeah it's just a wrapper for a map, but I like it as sort of a central place to get Data from.
I can do `Provider<Room>::Get("U-18")` for example and get the object that was loaded inside from who cares where from.

I acknowledge how frowned upon it is to have global objects like this, but this is not part of a public API and only used in personal projects where the team is ok with using it.

What I want to know is if there is a name for this pattern, if it even is one. I always called it Provider-Pattern since thats what it does, provide stuff, but I saw that thats already taken.

And please refrain from telling just how bad this code is and how I should feel bad for it.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a design pattern. It looks like a wrapper

Comment: Actually this makes me think of a **singleton** kind of thing

Comment: How does any data ever get inside your std::map? 
It may be an anti-pattern...

Comment: @CashCow that's the point. Its an unmodifiable set of constant data that doesn't need to be mutated. Such as in enums. `map` is allocated in the constructor i hope :D

Comment: It isn't unmodifiable though, it is returning TValue as non-const reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Singleton pattern, with the data item being a `map` (effectively an opaque associative container when access is through a getter and presumably setter).  An associative container isn't generally considered a design pattern in and of itself.

If you're looking for a phrase that communicates this design succinctly and clearly, something like a "Singleton map initialised (when/how) and read-only thereafter".

Comment: Aw damn, I forgot to say that it's not supposed to be a Singleton. The purpose is to simplify access to objects I like to store in a map. I guess it's not really anything but a wrapper for a container... I wonder if I can list Wrapper as a Design Pattern...

Comment: @xNidhogg Why are you keen to be able to say this is a design pattern? Is that to justify it? If it is a singleton (which it certainly seems to be), then it's an anti-pattern, not to be encouraged or boasted about.

Comment: @PeterWood I need to implement a design pattern in an assignment (not Singleton, for obvious reasons). I just looked through all code I had and thought this one might implement one. Turns out it doesn't, it's just a wrapper. When looking through other patterns I found none that I could apply with a reason.

Comment: @xNidhogg If there aren't existing patterns you can find [bad smells in your code](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/bad-smells-in-code) and [replace them with patterns](http://www.industriallogic.com/xp/refactoring/catalog.html). See what smells you can find.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, issues I have with your class:

1. Is `Get()` really supposed to return `TValue` by non-const reference. This essentially makes `Get()` out to be a setter as well as a getter. If it implements through `std::map`'s `operator[]` then it will insert and create a default-constructed TValue and you can happily assign to it or modify it.
2. A static private member variable is usually wrong. Whenever you have one, you are better off hiding the member away completely in the anonymous namespace of the compilation unit.
3. As it's a template, where exactly do you instantiate the instances? Each instance will need to be instantiated separately.

Comment: Yeah, Get() is a bad name for it. You can indeed set and get and the code does nothing but `return _dataMap[key]` basically behaving just like a normal map if the key doesn't exist, create it. This is intended, but yeah the name sucks. The class is not supposed to be instantiated and is purely static access. I should have made a private constructor then...

Comment: I created it so I don't have to create several container classes for several objects I might want to store. Before this I found myself having several classes such as `RoomProvider`, `TextureProvider`. This is now the job for the compiler, hence the template parameters. So now I can just `#include "Provider.h"` and write `Provider<Room>` `Provider<Texture>` and use the static functions. There's also a clear function I didn't include here.